# Find combinations in arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an 2D-array like this in java

```
transmission communication tv television  
approach     memorycode  
methodact
```

I need to get all combinations like:

```
{transmission,approach,methodact},{transmission,memorycode,methodact},{communication,approach,methodact},...
```

Can someone provide an example that will work for nXn arrays, even if it has only two rows?

Comment: Okay. So, what have you written so far? What problems are you having with it? Also, if this is homework (which I suspect it is), it is considered proper around here to declare it as such. That doesn't mean you won't get help, but by being up front about it you might get help from people who would otherwise turn up their noses, thinking you're trying to fool us into doing your homework for you.

Comment: Wait a second Aruna, are you asking people to give you working code?

Comment: Leave comments on other people's answers to respond to them, not new answers.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
static Set<List<String>> allComb(String[][] opts) {

    Set<List<String>> results = new HashSet<List<String>>();

    if (opts.length == 1) {
        for (String s : opts[0])
            results.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s)));
    } else
        for (String str : opts[0]) {
            String[][] tail = Arrays.copyOfRange(opts, 1, opts.length);
            for (List<String> combs : allComb(tail)) {
                combs.add(str);
                results.add(combs);
            }
        }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: if i have 4x4 array,all strings in last row is added in one combiantion..I want only one string from each row in each of the combinations

Comment: Sorry, had a mistake in the code. Updated my answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This code in JavaScript can help you:

> var sampleArray = [["transmission","communication","tv","television"], ["approach","memorycode"], ["methodact"]];

var GetAllCombinations = function(array2d)
{

```
var ret=[];

var fn = function(arr,index,cur)
{
    var ret = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arr[index].length; i++)
    {
        var x = cur.slice(0);
        x.push(arr[index][i]);
        if (index == arr.length-1)
            ret.push(x);
        else
            ret = ret.concat(fn(arr,index+1,x));
    }
    return ret;
};
return fn(array2d,0,[]);
```

}
console.log(GetAllCombinations(sampleArray));

It builds all combinations starting with a given array, iterates over all the options for that level and call it recursively, then concatenate it with the result.