# Each Array with each

Tags: java, arrays, list, each

I am trying the following: I have n Arrays in a List.
Each array have variable size.

Example:

```
List<char[]> list = ArrayList<char[]>();
char[] a = {'0'};
char[] b = {'1','2'};
char[] c = {'3','4','5'};
list.add(a);list.add(b);list.add(c);
... algorithmus
```

Result should be something like:

```
0-1-3
0-1-4
0-1-5
0-2-3
0-2-4
0-2-5
```

To do that static, I would use three for loops. But I need it dynamicly.
Anyone any idea?

Comment: Looks like you need recursion to do this.

Comment: What code have you tried? This may be of interest - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018567/find-combinations-in-arrays